# Typography element in material ui version 5

Tags: material-ui

Hi I get this error when trying to use Typography element with material-ui-5:

export 'default' (imported as 'typography') was not found in '@mui/material/typography'

here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Typography from '@mui/material';


export default function Create() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Typography>
            Create Page
        </Typography>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I got the same error despite importing correctly. The solution was to restart react server.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
import {Typography} from '@mui/material';
```

or

```
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
```